# Calling a function or targeting an element in another controller in Titanium Alloy

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

So, I'm creating a custom modal window:

```
var modal = Alloy.createController('modal');
modal.getView().open();
```

Inside the Modal controller is a function called `changeTitle` and in the view is a label with the id `modalTitle`. What I'm trying to figure out is how to call either one from the controller that *launched* the Modal window.

I thought the following would call the function in the controller, but no dice:

```
modal.changeTitle('foo');
```

Similarly I thought the following would target the label in the newly created view, but again, no dice.

```
var modalWin = modal.getView();
modalWin.$.modalTitle = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to expose the function `changeTitle` to the world, using `exports`. So inside the modal controller you have created, it would look like this:

```
exports.changeTitle = function() {
    // Your function definition...
};
```

For the second part, once again, that is not globally available, I suppose you could do this inside your modal controller:

```
exports.$ = $;
```

Then what you wrote will work, but that seems very dangerous to expose the inner members to the outside world. I would nest only the functionality you need in a exposed function like above.

Comment: Thanks! Man you're all over my answers. I should just hire you for some dev work lol!